# A program compiles OK on GNAT for Windows, but on Ubuntu GNAT gives error that Yield is not in Ada.Dispatching

Tags: gnat

Why is there a difference between GNAT on Windows 7 and GNAT on Ubuntu?  I have
searched the web and cannot find any answers.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you have installed compilers for different versions of the language on the different system.